# Is there any way that I can write URL in django using annotations in python

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am from the Java Hibernate and Symfony2 background where I used to write the routing within the controller on the top of function like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/blog")
 */
class PostController extends Controller
{
```

I know its not available in Django but is there any way I can code some decorator etc. so that I can mention the URL like this:

```
@URL("/mytest")
class myView():
    pass
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: To extend @Enrico's comment. You can use Flask in much the same manner as Django as a wsgi code so deployment really isn't too much different and you get the syntax you're after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it would be *very undjangonic*, you could try something like this:

```
project/
    decorators.py
    views.py
    urls.py

# decorators.py
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.importlib import import_module
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, url

def URL(path):
    path = r'^%s$' % path[1:]  # Add delimiters and remove opening slash
    def decorator(view):
        urls = import_module(settings.ROOT_URLCONF)
        urls.urlpatterns += patterns('', url(path, view))
        return view
    return decorator

# views.py
from .decorators import URL

@URL('/')
def home(request):
    # your view

@URL('/products')
def products(request):
    # your view


# urls.py
from django.conf.urls import patterns

from . import views  # import the modules with your views

urlpatterns = patterns('',)  # create an empty url dispatcher to append to
```

And make sure every file containing this decorator is imported before processing urls (e.g. by importing them in the urls file).

Comment: thanks buddy , i will try that. 1. Where do i have to write that code in which file 2. suppose i use this in view.py , how can i import it. can u give me some example

Comment: edit reflects these answers: 1. write this code in any file that you can import, I put it in `decorators.py`
2. just import the module like you would normally, I did a relative import of `views.py`

Comment: i get this error `AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'ROOT_URL_CONF'`

Comment: I'm sorry, that should be `ROOT_URLCONF`

Comment: Why is this considered undjangonic?