# DetailView template not displaying model data

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-class-based-views

I have a model which I want to display as a Detail view, I have created a list view that has a link that leads to its detailed view. I dont get any errors but the template doesn't render any of the models detail
Link to DetailView

```
<a href="../ancillaries/{{ Ancillary.id }}" > Product </a>
```

Model

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class Ancillary(models.Model):
     product_code = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True)
     type = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True)
     product = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True)
     standard = models.CharField(max_length=120,   null=True)
     measurement = models.CharField(max_length=120,  null=True)
     brand = models.CharField(max_length=120,   null=True)

     class Meta:
          verbose_name_plural = "Ancillaries"
     def get_absolute_url(self):
          return reverse('ancillaries')
     def __unicode__(self):
          return u'%s %s %s %s %s %s  %s' % (self.id, self.product_code, self.type, 
                                self.product, self.standard, 
                                self.measurement, self.brand)
```

View

```
class AncillaryDetail(DetailView):
    model = Ancillary
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

        context = super(AncillaryDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

       context['ancillary_list'] = Ancillary.objects.all()
       return context
```

Urls

```
url(r'^ancillaries/(?P<pk>\d+)/', AncillaryDetail.as_view(template_name='ancillary-detail.html')),
```

Template

```
{% for ancillary_list in object_list %}
{{ Ancillary.product}}
{{ Ancillary.type }}
{{ Ancillary.brand }}
{{ Ancillary.measurement }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: The template above looks like a list view. What template are you using for your detail view and why are you adding all your objects back into the detail context?

Comment: Oh no, the template above is what I used for the detail view. I didn't know what template to use to display the detail view data.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks as though you've used the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/) but adapted the [`ListView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview) example incorrectly. If you want to display a single model instance then the [`DetailView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#django.views.generic.detail.DetailView) is the correct view.

As @mrkre suggested you should name your URL pattern (although I would use the singular form for the name).

```
url(r'^ancillaries/(?P<pk>\d+)/', AncillaryDetail.as_view(
                template_name='ancillary-detail.html'), name="ancillary_detail")
```

The view is then simply

```
class AncillaryDetail(DetailView):
    model = Ancillary
```

In the template `ancillary-detail.html` you access the model instance using the default name `object`.

```
{{ object.product}}
{{ object.type }}
{{ object.brand }}
{{ object.measurement }}
```

Comment: See the comment by Berislav Lopac in the answer, below, I believe it applies to this answer as well. 
"I would just add that you should avoid putting template_name in the URLconf -- rather, put it in the definition of AncillaryDetail, right under the model attribute. "

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
{% for ancillary in ancillary_list %}
    {{ ancillary.product}}
    {{ ancillary.type }}
    {{ ancillary.brand }}
    {{ ancillary.measurement }}
{% endfor %}
```

I would suggest using names for url:

```
url(r'^ancillaries/(?P<pk>\d+)/', AncillaryDetail.as_view(), name="ancillary_details")

<a href="{% url 'ancillary_details' pk=ancillary.pk %}">
```

Place this right after your DetailView

```
template_name='ancillary-detail.html'
```

Comment: I would just add that you should avoid putting `template_name` in the URLconf -- rather, put it in the definition of `AncillaryDetail`, right under the `model` attribute.

Comment: I agree, that's what I do too. Edited answer.

Comment: @BerislavLopac - does this not allow more control over the url/template in a similar way that Flask does it? In other words, allowing a one to one mapping?

Comment: Not sure what you meant, but the way Django handles URLs is that they're registered in `patterns`; your URL would still need to be registered somehow. If you had a CBV attribute like, say, `view_url`, the class would still need a method to be called to register it.

Comment: Flask does that using decorators, and there is one such option for Django described in the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/13638521/122033, and I've seen others in the wild. But note that this is, as the linked answer states, quite un-djagostic, and it loses the option of importing package URLs we have now.